# Unity 5 - Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

please help me. I am trying to compile my project to android and i throws me this error. I was getting an error of "Unable to list target platforms". I replaced a "tools" folder in SDK Android folder to older one. It fixed that error, but started to throw this. I hope, you know what to do with it.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/CallM/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:44, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:45] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity] element:
  <activity
--    @android:name="com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity"
--    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
--</activity>
  <activity
++    @android:name="com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity">
++</activity>
++(end reached)
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:41, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:69] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen] element:
  <activity
      @android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
--    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
  <activity
      @android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
++    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:42, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:71] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser] element:
  <activity
      @android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
--    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
  <activity
      @android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
++    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:64, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:99] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.appodeal.ads.VideoPlayerActivity] element:
  <activity
--    @android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
--    @android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoPlayerActivity">
  <activity
++    @android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoPlayerActivity"
++    @android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:50, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:80] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/service[@name=com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService] element:
  <service
      @android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService"
              @android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService">
              @android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
--    </intent-filter>
--    <meta-data
--        @android:name="metrica:api:level"
  <service
      @android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService"
      <intent-filter>
              @android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService">
              @android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
++        <data
++            @android:scheme="metrica">
++        </data>
]
stdout[
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:20, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:24] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.appodeal.ads.InterstitialActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:21, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:25] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.appodeal.ads.VideoActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:22, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:27] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.appodeal.ads.LoaderActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:24, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:31] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:25, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:33] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:26, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:35] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:27, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:37] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:28, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:38] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:29, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:39] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:30, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:40] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:31, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:42] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=org.nexage.sourcekit.mraid.MRAIDBrowser] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:45, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:47] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.my.target.ads.MyTargetActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:33, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:49] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:32, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:51] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:34, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:54] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.appodeal.ads.networks.vpaid.VPAIDActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:35, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:56] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.appodeal.ads.networks.SpotXActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:46, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:58] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:36, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:60] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:37, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:61] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:38, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:62] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:39, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:63] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:40, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:67] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:43, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:73] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:47, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:75] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:48, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:77] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.startapp.android.publish.OverlayActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:49, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:79] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.startapp.android.publish.FullScreenActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:62, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:94] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:63, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:97] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:69, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:102] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.revmob.FullscreenActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:65, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:105] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:66, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:107] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:67, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:109] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:68, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:111] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:13, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:17] Skipping identical /manifest/application/receiver[@name=com.appodeal.ads.AppodealPackageAddedReceiver] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:57, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:88] Skipping identical /manifest/application/receiver[@name=com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:19, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:16] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.appodeal.framework] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:23, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cheetah-mobile\AndroidManifest.xml:29] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:23, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\MainLibProj\AndroidManifest.xml:13] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:24, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-10.2.6\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-auth-10.2.6\AndroidManifest.xml:8] Skipping identical /manifest/application/service[@name=com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-10.2.6\AndroidManifest.xml:4] Skipping identical /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:23, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element.
[Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:23, C:\Users\CallM\OneDrive\Dokumenty\Zapkix\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-10.2.6\AndroidManifest.xml:5] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=com.google.android.gms.version] element.
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

It is trying to merge multiple androidManifests.

Each throws me error.

1)

```
Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'> but library uses minSdkVersion='14'
```

2)

```
Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen] element:

UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

I would appreciate a little bit of help. Thank you.

Comment: I really would appreciate help. Please.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the first minSDK version error, you need to update the manifest to use the right version, change the line that says

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='9'>` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='14'>`

The second error I believe is coming from certain things being defined twice in the manifests it is trying to merge.

Have a look at this question for a more detailed response on the same issue: 
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1246689/unable-to-merge-android-manifests-trying-to-merge.html